# How can I make a containers Position: sticky; until scroll amount is met in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to recreate [this effect](https://the-goonies.webflow.io/) in WordPress using the Elementor builder, where the section stays the same/sticky until the user has scrolled a number of times/all the scroll effects are complete. Any advice on how I can best achieve this? Or if there is a plugin that does this?

From inspect, all I can see is that the container is set to "position: sticky;" but this is not working for me in Wordpress.[image: SectionInspect Result]

What additional steps do I need to take that I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried $(window).scroll() function?

JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var div_top = $('.sticky-bar').offset().top; //define your sticky div
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() + 61;

                    if (window_top > div_top) {
                        if (!$('.sticky-bar').is('.sticky')) {
                            $('.sticky-bar').addClass('sticky');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('.sticky-bar').removeClass('sticky');
                    }
                });
        });
});
```

CSS:

```
/* sticky state */
.sticky-bar.sticky {
  position: sticky;
}
/* normal state */
.sticky-bar {
  position: relative;
}
```